# NGINX: Redirect specific http URL to internal port, everything else being uplifted to https / 443

Tags: nginx, redirect, https

Sadly [nginx - Disable HTTPS redirection for specific URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55348265/nginx-disable-https-redirection-for-specific-url) was never answered, but since that question is over a year old, I'll try to rephrase mine a bit.

Got an nginx server that uplifts everything incoming to port 443 just fine.  Recently got a request to have a specific http (non 443) url/path proxy_passed to an internal server port that has some C-code listening on that port.

my current idea is:

```
   server {
     listen  80;

     location /controller {
       proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:8068;
     }
 
     if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
       rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;    # Redirect all non-SSL traffic to SSL.
     }
   }

   server {
     listen  443;
     ...etc
```

But as you can imagine, this only works if I comment out the if() block.  Does nginx have a reliable if-else block or something similar to accomplish what I need?  (I've heard the if parsing support was... iffy in nginx configurations)

I have, under the https server block have location redirects, like /api, being proxy_passed to a node app listening on port 3000, so I know that works well.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: You have `if ($ssl_protocol = "")` in a `server` block that listens only to port 80, so the condition will always be true. Instead of an `if` block, try: `location / { return 301 https://$host$request_uri; }`

Comment: ok with curl that works perfectly:  http:// example.com/controller hits port 8068 and i get a response back from the software at the other end.   https:// example.com/controller gives me a 404 - which is expected and i can trap that, and http anything else redirects to https and goes where it should.

but - doing the same tests in Chrome web browser has http:// example.com/controller route me back to the https 404 error.  all other test are the same as above.  any thoughts?

Comment: There's two reasons why the browser would do that. Either you didn't clear its cache and it is responding to an earlier version of your site, or you have HSTS headers on your secure site that prohibits browsers connecting over `http`.

Comment: silly cache kept getting in my way.  thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Richard Smith in the comments above.  The answer is (quoted):

"You have `if ($ssl_protocol = "")` in a server block that listens only to port 80, so the condition will always be true.

Instead of an if block, try: `location / { return 301 https://$host$request_uri; }`"

Which worked perfectly once browser cache issues were resolved (ie: turned off).